# Continuous press gesture on UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer

Is there any way to get notified for continuous press on `UIView`? i.e. I keep pressing `UIView` with one finger and i want to keep calling particular method during that duration again and again.

I tried `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but it just get notify of began, end, moved etc. Same as `TouchesBegan`.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, use the combine functionality of UILongPressGestureRecognizer and NSTimer.

The following code should meet your requirement.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

- (void) viewDidLoad

{

 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];

   [aView addGestureRecognizer: longPress];

}

- (void) longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture

{

      if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) 

  {

        self.timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(callMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        [self.timer fire];

 }
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )

    {

            [self.timer invalidate];

 }

}

- (void) callMethod

{

   //will be called continuously within certain time interval you have set

}
```

Answer (score 2):

fire `NSTimer` in `touchesBegan` to call a selector that you want and invalidate it in `touchesEnded` method

Comment: TouchesBegan and TouchesEnded :P

Answer (score 2):

On `TouchesBegan` start a timer and perform a selector when you've reached a desired amount of time (long press).
On `TouchesEnded` invalidate the timer to prevent the selector from being performed.

I would also set up an extra flag detecting "fingerReleased":
Set `fingerReleased = NO` on `TouchesBegan` and `fingerReleased = YES` on `TouchesEnded` and put the code you want to execute in a:

```
if (!fingerReleased) 
{
    // Execute code
}
```